Non-hamiltonian grid of points connected via lines
I have a 6x6 grid of points. For which I like to connect every 2 points to one another (exclusive connection betwen them) and cover the whole grid. Then figure out How many ways are possible? (Note the lines can be slanted and cover across few columns! But each point is connected to one another, and it's not shared (i.e. only 1 line goes in or out of each single point and not 2 - hence we cannot have a point being fed twice or feed twice)
Here's one example of an accepted output:
Show[ListPlot[{Tuples[Range[6], {2}]}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[6], Range[6]}],
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 6}, {1, 5}}], ListLinePlot[{{1, 4}, {1, 3}}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}]
 , ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}], ListLinePlot[{{2, 1}, {3, 1}}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{4, 1}, {5, 1}}]
 , ListLinePlot[{{5, 2}, {6, 1}}], ListLinePlot[{{6, 2}, {5, 3}}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{6, 3}, {6, 4}}]
 , ListLinePlot[{{6, 5}, {6, 6}}], ListLinePlot[{{5, 6}, {4, 5}}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{5, 5}, {4, 4}}]
 , ListLinePlot[{{4, 2}, {3, 2}}], ListLinePlot[{{5, 4}, {4, 3}}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{4, 6}, {3, 6}}]
 , ListLinePlot[{{2, 6}, {3, 5}}], ListLinePlot[{{2, 5}, {3, 4}}], 
 ListLinePlot[{{2, 4}, {3, 3}}]
 ]

Note that this is just one simple example, the lines can actually span longer diagonally across many columns, as long as they reach their intended target point.

Lines cannot cross, hence this is unacceptable:

And lines cannot overlap, hence this is also unacceptable:

Is there a systematic way of figuring this out? The points are not interconnected fully, hence this is certainly not a hamiltonian path. is this a manual effort (exhaustive/brute) or does Mathematica have a built-in function to deal with something like ths?

This seems more of a combinatorial problem than a problem of how to plot a given configuration, no?

I suppose there are many ways of looking at the problem - but yes ultimately the underlying algo may indeed be a combinatorics problem. The crossings would have to be negated algorithmically which I think is the main challenge

One nay start with FindHamiltonianCycle[GridGraph[{8, 8}]], highlighting it and then one should   to delete "even" edges.

Depth first search by recursive function call:
ClearAll[crossingQ,valid,addnewpair,n];

(* whether or not line segments {a,b} and {c,d} share a point*)

crossingQ[{{a_,b_},{c_,d_}}]:=(
   Det[{b-a,c-a}]*Det[{b-a,d-a}]<=0 &&
   Det[{d-c,a-c}]*Det[{d-c,b-c}]<=0);

(*find all point p in pts such that the line segment {v,p} does not contain any other points in pts.*)

valid[pts_List,v_]:=Union@@(Quiet[
  MinimalBy[#,Norm[#-v]&]& /@ GatherBy[pts,Divide@@(#-v)&]]);

(* addnewpair[] is the main recursive routine: input data are:
pts : a list of available points,
segments : a list of pairs of points which are already connected.

addnewpair[pts, segments] try to find a new pair {v1,v2} such that
v1=First[pts] and the line {v1,v2} has no common point 
with any member of `segments`. 
If such {v1,v2} is found, addnewpair[] calls itself with updated data. 
*)

addnewpair[{},segments_List]:=
    Sow[Graphics[{Blue,Thick,Line/@segments},GridLines->{Range[n],Range[n]}]];

addnewpair[pts_List,segments_List]:=Module[{v1=First[pts],v2candidates},
        v2candidates=Select[valid[Rest[pts],v1],
             Function[{v2},AllTrue[segments,Not[crossingQ[{#,{v1,v2}}]]&]]];
        Do[addnewpair[Complement[pts,{v1,v2}],Append[segments,{v1,v2}]],
             {v2,v2candidates}]
        ];

Sample run for $4\times 4$ grid is shown below. For $6\times 6$ grid, I didn't get any results even after an hour.
$Version
(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

n=4;
pts=Tuples[Range[n],{2}];
AbsoluteTiming[ans=Flatten@Last@Reap@addnewpair[pts,{}];]
(* {1.12877, Null} *)

Length[ans]
(* 730 *) 

GraphicsGrid[Partition[ans, UpTo[15]], ImageSize -> 600]



Hi @"A. Kato" : Any new ideas on how to do the 6x6 for this original question ? .... There must be a method that works timely.

@Steve237 The program perfectly works for 6x6 cases, too. The only problem is I don't have enough memory and time. The number of configuration would be huge, probably no smaller than 10^20. Do you really need all configuration ? Do you have a supercomputer ?

Therefore it's not an optimized solution

We first create a grid of points.
nn = 3;
d = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, nn}, {y, 0, nn}], 1];

Then we choose all possible start and endpoints of lines. Not to get each time the same solution, we randomly mix the lines:
lines = Line /@ Subsets[d, {2}];
lines = RandomSample[lines, Length[lines]];
n = Length[lines];

Now we start with the first line and add lines that doe not cross the lines we already have:
res = {lines[[1]]};
Do[If[AllTrue[res, 
    RegionIntersection[#, lines[[i]]] === EmptyRegion[2] &], 
   AppendTo[res, lines[[i]] ]], {i, 2, n}];

Finally we draw the lines:
Graphics[{Thickness[0.005], PointSize[0.02], res, Point[d]}, 
 Axes -> True]



Yes but where are all the possibilities? ....

-1. The points $(0,0)$ and $(0,2}$ are not covered.
